# Настройка nginx: не видно путь

Tags: сервер, nginx, unix

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться: какая из указанных настроек nginx мешает корректной работе с дирректориями?

**Проблема:**
Файлы в корне исполняются корректно, но как только нужно исполнить файл глубже, чем корень - nginx пытается всё равно искать его в корне.

**Пример:**
Если в `google.com/admin/index.php` делается запрос файла `/template/123.png` 
то он ищет его в `google.com/template/` а не в `google.com/admin/template/`

Настройки nginx:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name google.com;
    root /home/google/www/html;
    index index.php;

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }

        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        set     $path_info      $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $path_info;


        fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADMIN        email@example.com;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_SIGNATURE    nginx/$nginx_version;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
    }
}
```

**Лог**:

```
2017/11/26 22:41:35 [error] 31955#31955: *183 open() "/home/google/www/html/template/123.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 80.251.118.111, server: google.com, request: "GET /template/123.png HTTP/1.1", host: "google.com", referrer: "http://google.com/admin/index.php»
```

Файл лежит в `/home/google/www/html/admin/template/123.png`

Comment: `/template/123.png` — это же абсолютный путь (в данном контексте — от корня сайта). а `template/123.png` — это относительный путь.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, в логах вот так видно: server: google.com, request: "GET /template/123.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri; 
}
```

[Вот конфигурация](http://docs.joomla.org/Nginx), которую рекомендуют joomla под nginx.

Comment: Ну, не хочу я Jumla переписывать. Не мой мопед, нужно его просто разместить. При этом на хостингах он ведёт себя нормально. Наталкивает на мысль о том, что это решается настройкой.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить:

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
}

Вот конфигурация, которую рекомендуют joomla под nginx
https://docs.joomla.org/Nginx

Answer (score 1):

Я не совсем понимаю проблему. Оно работает как и должно, собственно. nginx от корня все пути начинает смотреть.

Если вы хотите, к примеру, чтоб запросы с `google.com/admin/index.php` шли не в `/template/`, а `/admin/template/`, то можете использовать `$http_referer` для редиректа куда надо.

Comment: А можно пример? Только учусь с nginx работать, не совсем ясно что сделать нужно.

P.S.: я просто беру CMS и там все линки строятся от исполняемого файла. Если исполняемый файл лежит в директории `admin/`, то ожидается поиск файлов относительно данной директории, а не корня

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился использованием целевого конфига от CMS

https://docs.joomla.org/Nginx